# parallelizing linear algebra using gsl library

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, linear-algebra, gsl

In my c++ scripts, I have many for loops to compute linear algebra operations. I am wondering what is the best way to make the loops parallel? One example is the following function which computes the kronecker product of two matrices.

```
void Kronecker(const gsl_matrix *K, const gsl_matrix *V, gsl_matrix *H) 
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<K->size1; i++) {
        for (size_t j=0; j<K->size2; j++) {
            gsl_matrix_view H_sub=gsl_matrix_submatrix (H, i*V->size1, j*V->size2, V->size1, V->size2);
            gsl_matrix_memcpy (&H_sub.matrix, V);
            gsl_matrix_scale (&H_sub.matrix, gsl_matrix_get (K, i, j));
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

How can I improve the computation time of my code, when I have `for loops` which can be parallel?

Comment: How does the dependencies between the computations look like? Are there any?

Comment: @FidelCastro Definitely I can make the computation parallel similar to above example.

Comment: Maybe this survey is a start, to look how others do it: bit.ly/la-sw-survey-2021

Comment: The biggest speed improvement can be expected if you profile your code and focus on hot spots -- rewrite them to be cache and vectorization friendly.

Comment: @Laci the biggest bottleneck of my code is matrix inversion which is produced by kronecker product and I don't know whether there is a technique to reduce the computational time of my code or not. Here is a [post in stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808908/computing-the-inversion-of-a-matrix-which-is-the-sum-of-a-kronecker-product-and) about how this matrix looks like. I will appreciate if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the memory layout, allocations, syscalls, and potential side-effects in your underlying gsl calls, a really easy way to get parallelization is via OpenMP.  That of course introduces a dependency and requires compiler support, but it's particularly effective on simple loops like yours.  Untested and probably needs a bit more to ensure H is written properly, but something like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j)
for (size_t i=0; i<K->size1; i++) {
    for (size_t j=0; j<K->size2; j++) {
        gsl_matrix_view H_sub=gsl_matrix_submatrix (H, i*V->size1, j*V->size2, V->size1, V->size2);
        gsl_matrix_memcpy (&H_sub.matrix, V);
        gsl_matrix_scale (&H_sub.matrix, gsl_matrix_get (K, i, j));
    }
}
```

See https://curc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming/OpenMP-C.html for more details.

If you don't want to introduce the dependency or have some other constraint (e.g., OpenMP can be problematic in library code), you can always do it yourself by having the inner for loop in a thread, kicking off N threads at the start and joining at the end.  That's of course assuming you have enough work, which seems like you might if the matrices are big enough.

Comment: Note that `private(i,j)` should be deleted from the OpenMP directive.

Comment: Regarding the value of `K->size1`, it can be better to use a `collapse(2)` clause. Besides, the computation will be memory-bound and memory-bound codes generally do not scale. One solution to improve the scalability and performance overall is to compute the `H_sub.matrix = V * gsl_matrix_get(K, i, j)` expression using basic loops in one unique operations rather than two (2x faster). If `V` is non contiguous, copying it in a contiguous block will also speed up the computation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will be much help but I do have an [old example](https://github.com/Eastonco/CS360/blob/master/lab4/src/pivot.c) of using the `pthread.h` library to compute Gauss elimination with partial pivoting matrices.

In summary, the highlights are:

- Create an array of threads `pthread_t threads[N];`
- initlize the halting barrier for threads to run to `pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, numThreads);`
- Set your barriers in the function you're trying to multithread so that it will wait until each function has the dependencies needed to continue. Add `pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);` at your points
- Start your threads

```
    for (i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, functionWithThreading, (void *)i);
    }
```

- Finally, wait for all the threads to finish and join them up

```
    for (i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
```

I know this might not be the exact solution you're looking for but I hope the example might help